# Add products from external site and make connection from Java with Magento

Tags: java, soap, magento-1.7

I want to add multiple product to cart from my external site. 
I can add single product using this url :

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/cart/add?product=2&qty=2
```

but for multiple I can’t use like this : `http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/cart/add?product=2&qty=2&product=3&qty=4`.

Is there any other way to do this ? My external source site is in JSP.

And I want to make connection to magento database using Java. So, Is there any tutorials or examples for Connection using Java? I know that SOAP & RPC can be used, but I don't know how to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've written this code, into "CartController.php" file.

```
public function newAction() {
    $cart = $this->_getCart();
    try {
        //getting list of products
        $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode()));
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
            echo '<br>';
            $param = $_GET['product' . $i];
            if (isset($param)) {
                $param = explode("/", $param);
                print_r($param);
                $productId = $param[0];
                $product = $this->addNewProduct($productId);
                $quantity = $filter->filter($param[1]);
                $params['product'] = $product;
                $params['qty'] = $quantity;

                $cart->addProduct($product);
            }// if over
        }//for over
        $cart->save();
        $message = $this->__('Added to Your Cart Successfully', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml());
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        $this->_redirect("checkout/cart/");
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {}
```

Now, we can add products, like this : `http://localhost/magento/index.php/checkout/cart/new?product1=2/3&product2=3/3&product3=4/1`

Where, in "product1=2/3" 2=>productId & 3=> it's quantity.

This code is working properly. But,I want to do this without modifying client's code.